# PHP If statement not working when checking an Array

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this If statement to check user submitted data. The data is first turned into an array which is then passed to a function where this if statement is located.

```
$errCount = 0;
$errMSG ='';
// Check Name
if ($submitData['FullName'] != '') {
    if (strlen ($submitData['FullName']) < 4) {
        $errCount + 1;
        $errMSG .='The Full Name was too short!';
    }
} else {
    $errCount + 1;
    $errMSG .='The Full Name Field was left blank!';
}
```

When this is run, even with an empty string, none of the errors are being triggered.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: The error count remains 0 and there is not error message -> even with a blank submission.

Comment: You are not incrementing `$errCount`..  `$errCount += 1;`

Comment: `submitData` what is that change that to `$_POST['FullName']`

Comment: I think the Incrementing did the trick. Thanks.  BTW the Array that I had was:   $submitData = array(
   "FullName" => $_POST['fname'],
   "Username" => $_POST['name'],
   "Password" => $_POST['pass'],
   "EMail" => $_POST['email'],
   "Agreement" => $_POST['agree'],         
  );

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning values to $errCount varaible when incrementing it;

```
$errCount = 0;
$errMSG ='';
$submitData['FullName']='';
// Check Name
if ($submitData['FullName'] != '') {

if (strlen ($submitData['FullName']) < 4) {
    $errCount=$errCount + 1; // or u can write  $errCount++;
    $errMSG .='The Full Name was too short!';
    }
} else {

 $errCount=$errCount + 1; // or u can write  $errCount++;
$errMSG .='The Full Name Field was left blank!';
}

echo $errMSG;

echo $errCount;
```

This will work.....

Answer (score 0):

```
$errCount = 0;
$errMSG ='';
// Check Name

if(isset($submitData['FullName']) && strlen ($submitData['FullName'])>0 && strlen ($submitData['FullName'])<4)
{
    $errCount++;
    $errMSG .='The Full Name was too short!';
}
else if($submitData['FullName'] == '')
{
    $errCount++;
    $errMSG .='The Full Name Field was left blank!';
}
else
{
    //success
}
```